# Add realted products in VARIABLE product Woocomerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to change the position of related products within a product page. If the product is "single" it works fine:

```
remove_action ('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
add_action ('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 5);
```

How can I do the same on a variable product page?

And if someone knows, how can I eliminate "related products" at the bottom that was showing before?

Thank you

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wt-woocommerce-related-products/ - Give it a try